# Tortoise SVN: Do I lose my changes when I reload a file that's been modified by someone else?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit, reload

I am editing the same index.jsp file with another colleague and we use Tortoise SVN for Subversion. He commits his changes and Weblogic tells me that the file I am editing has been modified. If I choose to reload the file, do I lose the changes that I've done locally but not committed?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do an update. Then you most likely will face a merge conflict that you just have to resolve. You will not lose your changes.